# $.getJSON wrong URL in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, knockout.js, laravel

I'm utilizing Laravel 4 PHP MVC framework and Knockout.js for a simple app I'm doing.

I have set up a RESTful API and want to do a `$.getJSON` request from the client but the get request is sent to the wring URL.

Instead of doing a `GET` to `http://mydomain.com/users/123Fdfsd02/reports` Knockout sends the request to `http://mydomain.com/users/reports` which is the wrong URL.

This is my Knockout code:

```
function ReportViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.report = ko.observable();  

    self.getAllReports = function(data) {
        $.getJSON("reports", function(data) {
            self.report(data);
        });
    }

    self.getAllReports();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ReportViewModel());
```

What am I missing here? I've tried setting the url to `./reports` and `reports` but still no luck.

Thanks for helping out a newb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I throw this in the header view partial in my Laravel projects, before other scripts that might need it:

```
<script>
    var BASE_URL = "{{ URL::to('/') }}";
</script>
```

Then I can assemble AJAX calls like...

```
 $.getJSON(BASE_URL+"api/content", params, function(response) {
     //whatever 
 });
```

And it'll all work whether the app is running from a subfolder of my localhost, or on staging or production environments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be smarter to just make use of an absolute path insted of a relative path.

Can you construct the path `/users/123Fdfsd02/reports` with variables? Or is this not possible?

Which URL is shown in the addressbar of your browser? Maybe `http://mydomain.com/users`?

Comment: the url in my browser is mydomain.com/users/123Fdfsd02 so I'm wondering why the request url is stripped from the "123Fdfsd02". The API is not set up in a way so that I can create the URL dynamically as I thought that wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Maybe just make use of `window.location.href + '/reports'`

Comment: Sorry, its rather `window.location.pathname + '/reports'`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
var rootUrl = "/users/"+ userToken +"/reports"
```

Where userToken can be find this way :

```
s = document.location.href;
s = s.replace('http://mydomain.com/users/', '');

userToken=  s.substring(0, s.indexOf('/'));
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: how is userToken defined then?

Answer (score 0):

Personaly, I would do that this way:

Set up HTML, with 'base' tag. "base" tag will ensure every relative URL will be prepended with the value of its 'href' attribute, so AJAX call to relative URL `user/detail/1` will go to this absolute URL -> `http://mydomain.com/user/detail/1`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    <base href="http://mydomain.com/">
    ...
```

Then, use relative URL in AJAX call(s), based on the root URL defined in 'base' tag

```
function ReportViewModel() {
    ...

        $.getJSON("users/123Fdfsd02/reports",
    ...
};
```

Bulletproof solution is to use absolute URLs.